# Put a JTextArea in specific location

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, jtextarea

I want to know, how can I put my `JTextArea`, down of some buttons I have in my program... To show you how I want to order this, I made an example in a GUI.

Image example:

[image]

Basically, I want to put them down of the buttons, like in the example.
I try to put a JPanel as flowlayout, and add the JTextArea, but dont works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, as suggested a `BorderLayout`is appropriate for the main panel.

To be the closer possible to your example, I added a margin (an empty border) to the north panel, as well as a horizontal strut between the buttons (with the use of a `BoxLayout`for the north panel).

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
buttonsPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");

buttonsPanel.add(b1);
buttonsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
buttonsPanel.add(b2);

contentPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
contentPanel.add(new JTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you Berger, this is I need, I  tryed for hours and dont works, I used a borderlayout in my frame and put a Jpanel as flowlayout to add my buttons up, but when I want to put the jtextarea, nothings works...     

But I try with your code and runs. Thank you for your time and help guys, I really appreciate.

Comment: With `new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)` you are hard-coding the amount of space used. This is not portable.

Answer (score 3):

You can have use BorderLayout and add the JTextArea to Center and have layout for button panel as FlowLayout and add it to the North. Let me know if you need hep with code.

Comment: Thank you too Beniton, I really apprecaite your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `BorderLayout` and most other layout managers such as `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout` is that they set gaps between components in pixels. This is not portable because on different screens the layout will
look different. If you create your UI on a 19" monitor it will not look
good on a 32" monitor. Now we are talking about Java application, where portability is paramount.

Fortunately, with `GroupLayout` or `MigLayout`, we can create truly portable UI.

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutTwoButtonsEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutTwoButtonsEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("B1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("B2");
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(15, 28);
        area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        createLayout(btn1, btn2, area);

        setTitle("MigLayout example");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("gap 5lp 7lp"));

        add(arg[0], "split 2");
        add(arg[1], "wrap");
        add(arg[2], "push, grow, span");
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutTwoButtonsEx ex = new MigLayoutTwoButtonsEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an example with the `MigLayout` manager.

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("gap 5lp 7lp"));
```

We use logical pixels to define our gaps.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the example]

Comment: Thank you Jan, sorry for answerd too late, but I not login in some time.